# matplotlib, savefig: DPI setting is ignored

Tags: python, matplotlib, show, dpi

I cannot find anyone else with this problem. In matplotlib, you can view your plots using either show() or savefig(). These generate slightly different images; in my case, the savefig() image is uglier and harder to understand. I need to make life easy for my examinator, so..

I found some topics that suggested I set the DPI size to match that of show(). I have tried:

-> Setting savefig.dpi directly with matplotlib.rcParams['savefig.dpi'] = 80.

-> Setting savefig.dpi directly in ~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc.

-> Moving my rc file to CWD.

-> Finally, using savefig('image.pdf', dpi=80)

I can verify that the attribute is indeed getting set; but it seems that the setting is igored by savefig(). Can anyone help with this?

(Simplified) code:

```
plt.bar(ind, functimes, yerr=stddev, bottom=0, width=barWidth, align='center', color='b')

ax = plt.gca()
ax.legend(barRcts, barLegend)
plt.title("Function Call Overhead")
plt.xlabel("Function ID")
plt.ylabel("Execution Time [us]")

plt.xticks(ind, funcNames)
figtest.autofmt_xdate()

plt.savefig(out_file, dpi=80, format='pdf')
```

Comment: `matplotlib` saves `pdf` files in vector format. Unless you have bitmap images in there, DPI is rather meaningless in a vector image since they are resolution independent.

Comment: Aha, I understand. So there is no way to save pdf images with savefig() so that they are identical to those you can save (manually) with show()?

Comment: They should be identical. The only difference might be if you resize the figure before saving it. But you can also set the size of your figure (`figure((width, height))`) and `savefig` will use that.

Comment: Yup, that did it. Thanks a lot, saved me many precious hours :)

Answer (score 5):

PDF saving uses the DPI setting for image resolution inside the PDF, not for any line/polygon resolution (which is meaningless in a vector format).

If your happy with the output on screen, and don't need to have a scalable graphic, saving as `png` is probably fine.

Comment: But note that if you have used `contourf` (for example) you get a raster image inside your pdf/svg, so dpi is meaningful again.

Comment: @ChrisH - I don't agree. Contourf produces vector output not raster. imshow however does produce an image so (from memory) there exists an image dpi to assist. HTH

Comment: it turns out you're right - according to my 5.5 MB .svg that slows inkscape to an absolute crawl.  Then dpi settings help get the linewidth right for axes and overlaid lines. I'd realised this a while ago but forgot to log in and update.

Answer (score 1):

On your IDE, when you pass the cursor over the function `plt.savefig()` it shows the next: `(function) savefig: (*args: Any, **kwargs: Any)` it means that the function only accepts unlimited arguments `(*args)` and Keyworded Arguments `(**kwargs)`. So, if you go the documentation of Matplotlib you will find the arguments you could use https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html.

Now, if you only want to present a good quality plots you could do the next as an example. Open a jupyter notebook on vscode and code `plt.savefig("my_image.jpg", dpi = 300)` [dpi stands for dots per inch, if you use a higher dpi you will get a high quality image] then with markdown show your plots with the following code:

```
plt.plot(a,v_t_retraso, 'r', label = 'FP - retraso')
plt.plot(a,v_t_adelanto,'b', label = 'FP - adelanto')

plt.title('Caracteristicas de los terminales', fontdict={'fontname': 'Comic Sans MS', 'fontsize': 20})

# Escalando
plt.yticks([400,450,500,550])
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Corriente en Linea, $A$')
plt.ylabel('Voltaje en los terminales, $V$')
plt.savefig('terminales_4.jpg', dpi=300)
plt.close()

plt.plot(v_t_retraso,a)
plt.xlabel('Corriente en Linea, $A$')
plt.ylabel('Voltaje en los terminales, $V$')
plt.savefig('terminales_5.jpg', dpi=300)
plt.close()
```

With the save images you could open a cell on markdown and write the following code:

```
 <!-- If you want a full-size image then use the following code: -->
 <!-- ![](terminales_4.jpg)  ![](terminales_5.jpg) -->
 <!-- For custom size -->
<img src="terminales_4.jpg" alt="terminales_4" style="width:432px;"/>
<img src="terminales_5.jpg" alt="terminales_5" style="width:432px;"/>
```

[image: Code Example on Jupyter Notebook]

Finally you could export your code as HTML or Pdf and show as many graphs as you want. An example is shown in the next image.

[image: Result of the example]